# How can I "replace" a selected text-range in a textarea in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, contenteditable

I'm trying to use Javascript to replace the selected text in an arbitrary selected TEXTAREA node in Chrome (! not a content editable div !) The code fragment I see repeated in lots of places to replace selected text basically does this:

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
range.insertNode( document.createTextNode("test "));
```

However, this does not work for input fields such as TEXTAREA or INPUT TYPE=TEXT. The text is inserted BEFORE the TEXTAREA instead of inside it.

There is an alternative method to modify the selection text inside a text area using textarea.selectionStart and textarea.selectionEnd. However, these require figuring out which textarea element is actually active/selected. Chrome/Webkit document.activeElement seems to be broken and has been broken for a long time. I can't figure out any workaround to find the "currently selected textarea". See the bug here...

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=14436

You can see a micro-demo of the problem I'm trying to solve here.

http://dj1.willowmail.com/~jeske/_drop/insertIssue/1.html

http://ajaxandxml.blogspot.com/2007/11/emulating-activeelement-property-with.html

Any thoughts on this?

Given a webpage with an arbitrary bit of text selected in an arbitrary TEXTAREA node, without knowing ahead of time what textarea the focus is in, how do I find the active textarea and replace the selected text with some other text?

(( FYI: I'm using this code in a Chrome extension. An in-page javascript content script is extending the page javascript, so I have no idea what the page structure is ahead of time. It needs to work for any webpage. ))

Comment: I've just made an example http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/VDsHf/ and seems it's working properly. Based on this example can you say is it working same  as you are expecting or not. If not, what's wrong there? And another example which is exatcly **replacing** the selected text: http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/VDsHf/3/

Comment: you are using contenteditable divs, which works fine. I'm having a problem when the selection is in a TEXTAREA or INPUT TYPE=TEXT. I need it to work in TEXTAREA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that as of 8/23/2012, [Chrome does not properly support activeElement](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=14436), as it is often set to "body" when it shouldn't be.

There may also be some challenges because in my chrome extension, right-clicking to get a context menu might be altering the activeElement.

The solution was to provide a `focus` handler to create a more reliable activeElement in Chrome, and then use direct interaction with the TEXTAREA to handle the selection replacement.

```
var dActiveElement = null;

function _dom_trackActiveElement(evt) {
    if (evt && evt.target) {
      dActiveElement = evt.target;
      console.log("focus on: " + dActiveElement.nodeName + 
                  " id: " + dActiveElement.id);
    } else {
      console.log("focus else..");
    }
}

if (document.addEventListener) {
   document.addEventListener("focus",_dom_trackActiveElement,true);
}

function insertTextAtCursor(text) {
    console.log("insertTextAtCursor : " + text);    

    if (dActiveElement.nodeName.toUpperCase() == "TEXTAREA") {
       console.log("selection in textarea!  id: " + dActiveElement.id);

       var ta = dActiveElement;
       var saveSelectionStart = ta.selectionStart;

       var newvalue = ta.value.slice(0,ta.selectionStart) + 
                         text + ta.value.slice(ta.selectionEnd,ta.length);
       console.log("output : " + newvalue  + ", len : " + newvalue.length);
       var newSelectionEnd = ta.selectionStart + text.length;

       ta.value = newvalue;
       ta.selectionStart = ta.selectionEnd = (newSelectionEnd);       
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem you may be having is that the active element changes as a result of clicking the button before your code runs. If you instead use the `mousedown` event and prevent the default button action, it works fine in Chrome:

http://jsfiddle.net/b3Fk5/2/

Comment: Thanks for this, but that is just a fix for the "micro test" I created for this question. In my "real" use case, the replace function is triggered by a chrome extension message sent from a context-menu trigger. Your fix method isn't usable in that case. See my solution based on my own focus handler.